# Pasar variable $_GET de Ajax al controlador

Tags: php

Tengo esta función:

```
public function GestorGaleriaOperadorCafe(){

    $datos=$this->imagenTemporal;
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $respuesta=controllerOperadorCafes::mostrarImagenOfertasController($datos,$id);
     echo $respuesta;

     }
```

Con esa funcion que recibo datos por ajax, paso los datos hacia el controlador
, si intento recibir la variable por el controlador directamente no me funciona

```
public function mostrarImagenOfertasController($datos,$id){



        $datosController=array("ruta"=>$ruta,
                                "id"=>$id);

        DatosOperadorCafe::subirImagenOfertasgaleriaModel($datosController,"galeria_ofertas_cafe");
        $respuesta=DatosTienda::mostrarImagenOfertasgaleriaModel($datosController,"galeria_ofertas_cafe");

        echo $respuesta['ruta'];

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Si no estas usando algun interceptor de ruta y/o framework la unica forma de recibir los parametros de una requision en php es a traves de $_GET[]. Usas algun framework?

Comment: No estoy usando ningún Framework

Comment: A que te refieres con un interceptor?

Comment: Podria decirse que es un patron de diseño que permite simplificar el procesamiento repetitivo entre elementos de software, por ejemplo un ejemplo es la recepción de una requisión  en el servidor web y evaluar los valores de la requisión. Muchos framework realizan esa intercepcion de manera muy transparente, pero otorga la simplificacion de paso de parametros y/o aspectos de seguiridad
Tambien se lo indica como middleware

Un ejemplo seria la forma que Laravel te permite leer los paramentros de la requisión en tu controlador de ruta  `$request->route('parameter_name')`

Answer (score 0):

por lo que veo las variables `$id` y `$ruta`son locales de la función, creo que te falta usar el `$this`

```
$this->datos=$this->imagenTemporal;
$this->id=$_GET['id'];

/*******/

$datosController=array("ruta"=>$this->ruta,
                            "id"=>$this->id);
```

> no se te olvide crear las variables globales

Comment: Estoy intentando así y no he tenido éxito

`<?php 

class AjaxOC{
  public $id;
  public function GestorGaleriaOperadorCafe(){

   $datos=$this->imagenTemporal;
   $this->id=$_GET['id'];
   $respuesta=controllerOperadorCafes::mostrarImagenOfertasController($datos,$id);
    echo $respuesta;
 
  }

  
 }

 if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
  $c= new AjaxOC();
  $c->id= $_GET['id'];
  $c->GestorGaleriaOperadorCafe();

 ?>`